# Recv pieces of input message using recvFrom with UDP sockets in C

Tags: linux, sockets, udp

I've got a custom application message protocol  defined over UDP, which expects a FIXED header, composed by a 4 fields of size 32-bits and an optional payload.

Hi would like to develop my Server application in a way that:

1. Receives the header
2. Parses the header
3. understands the number of bytes inside the payload
4. Receives the payload.

Is this a feasible way to develop UDP server or I must receive the message in a bigger buffer and parse it all toghether ?

Thanks for your answers!